# canonize function in boost filesystem3

Tags: c++, boost, path

I'm seeing that the following section in boost/filesystem3/path.hpp

```
//  older functions no longer supported
// ...
//basic_path& canonize();
```

What equivalent can I use to archieve the same goal on an incoming boost::filesystem::path? I have boost version 1.47. I'm seeing the `canonical(...)` function in the online docs, but I cannot find it in my headers. Let's say I cannot upgrade. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the `normalize()` function does the same thing.

Comment: `'normalize' : is not a member of 'boost::filesystem'`

Comment: @Notinlist - it's a member function of `boost::filesystem::path`.

Comment: Yes. Found it. The problem is that it is not present in 1.49 documentation. Sigh... Will use that and place comments around for the case of upgrading. :-)

Comment: @Notinlist - Looking at the 1.49 documentation (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#canonical). `path` also has `canonical()` and `absolute()` member functions which look promising. I've been using `normalize()` since at least 1.47. Now I wonder if it's some kind of helper function and I should be using one of the documented functions.